# create json array and append objects in it from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

At this moment I'm trying to create a json like this.

```
[
{"name": "set registry key right",
"win_acl": {
  "path": "HKCU:\\Bovine\\Key",
  "user": "BUILTIN\\Users",
  "rights": "EnumerateSubKeys",
  "type": "allow",
  "state": "present",
  "inherit": "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit",
  "propagation": "None"
}
},
{
"name": "Remove FullControl AccessRule for IIS_IUSRS",
"win_acl": {
  "path": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MySite",
  "user": "IIS_IUSRS",
  "rights": "FullControl",
  "type": "allow",
  "state": "absent",
  "inherit": "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit",
  "propagation": "None"
}
}
]
```

I want to create it dynamically trough javascript.

This is what I have now:

```
    function GenerateYaml(btn) {
    $('#generatedYamlTextField').removeAttr("hidden");

    var id = btn.replace("generateBtn", "");
    var moduleName = $("#formpanel" + id).attr("data-title-caption");

    //Looping trough panels
    $("#formpanel" + id).each(function () {

        var json = "[\n{\n\"name\":\"" + "module beschrijving" + "\",\n";
        json += "\"" + moduleName + "\": {\n";
        //Looping through labels in the panel to create the object
        $('label').each(function (index, value) {
                            var is_last_item = (index == ($('label').length - 1));

            if (!is_last_item) {
                json += "\"" + value.innerText + "\":"+"\"textboxvalue\",\n";
            } else {

                json += "\"" + value.innerText + "\":"+"\"textboxvalue\"\n";

            }

        });

        json += "}\n},]\n";
        $("#yamltextfield").append(json);

    });   
}
```

This is what I get from above code in my textarea:

```
[
{
"name":"module beschrijving",
"win_acl_inheritance_module": {
"path":"textboxvalue",
"reorganize":"textboxvalue",
"state":"textboxvalue"
}
},]
```

My problem is that I have multiple panels and I want to add them in the same array so that I get it like the json I showed in the first place.

I hope you guys could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Greetings,
Mouaad

Comment: Why are you forming the json string yourself?

Comment: Never ever manually create json strings. It is error prone and far more work that using serializer to convert to and from arrays/objects

Comment: I don't know how to create one dynamically :/

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: Make array of objects and use `JSON.stringify()` once whole array is populated

Comment: Note you can see how error prone it is. You have a trailing `,` which makes your string invalid as JSON. Paste that result into a json validator like jsonlint.com

Comment: Yes, you right guys. I'm going to find another solution, with adding objects into arrays.

Comment: `$("#formpanel" + id).each` .. doesn't make sense either since element id's must be unique by definition

Comment: Provide sample html in order to get a better working solution

Comment: @charlietfl its unique by definition cuz I create the panel for every click in select box..

Answer (score 0):

Don't form the json string manually. Just compose your objects, put them in an array, say `arr` and you can get the json string by:

```
JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that out